# create atom from string and numbers in erlang

Tags: for-loop, erlang

I am new in Erlang and I would like to create atom from string and format. I also not sure how to have loop in erlang. This sudo code of is what I want:

```
For (int i = 0; i++; i < 10) {
    list_to_atom(lists:flatten(io_lib:format("certfile~B", [i])))
}
```

How can I have this in Erlang?

Comment: not sure that I understand question. Provide input data and expected output to your function.

Comment: If you have questions about Erlang maybe better ask in [special room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75358/erlang-otp). Such format more conveniently because each question on SO must be concrete.

Comment: Just be aware that dynamically making atoms in Erlang is generally a bad idea! The problem is that they are not garbage collected, so if you create too many it will crash the Virtual Machine

Comment: Thank you for your comments.. Asier answer was exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lists:map/2` function along with `lists:seq/2`:

```
lists:map(fun(I)->
           list_to_atom(lists:flatten(io_lib:format("certfile~B", [I])))
         end, lists:seq(1,10)).
```

`lists:seq/2` will generate a list of numbers and `lists:map/2` will change it to the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

...and using lists comprehensions:

```
ɐuıɥɔɐɯ@uplink:~/Workshop/Erlang$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.3  (abort with ^G)
1> R = lists:seq(1, 10).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
2> [list_to_atom(lists:flatten(io_lib:format("certfile~B", [X]))) || X <- R].
[certfile1,certfile2,certfile3,certfile4,certfile5,
 certfile6,certfile7,certfile8,certfile9,certfile10]
3>
```

Cheers!

By the way, I'm not sure if you are aware of it, but dynamically making  atoms is kind of discouraged in Erlang. There is a limited number of atoms you can use/create (pretty high, but limited) and they are not  garbage collected.